# Separating the Worker and Manager Nodes - How to replication the Manager Configuration in the work nodes

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am to configure the APIM Gateway with the Pattern Worker and Manager.

My doubt is how to replication the configuration maked in Manager to workers node.

Is possible to make only configuration in axis2.xml in worker and the others  configurations how(jms,thrift,enviroment) to replicate when the worker node start?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain further.

Comment: For example: I have the configurarion in the Gateway Manager but I will to start two nodes worker. I Have that to configure something at worker node further carbon.xml and axis.xml? I hope that configuration how api-manager.xml, jndi.properties etc, related about the Gateway isn´t necessary because already was configure in Manager.

Comment: In the Gateway Worker Node I hope that not necessary to configure anything because Worker will start with configuation maked in the Manager. This is correct? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The manager does not share configurations with worker nodes. Worker-manager pattern is used to share deployable artifacts from manager to workers. So you have to do configurations in all nodes.

But you can automate this process using a tool like puppet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.